# Wifi Adapter TL-WN821n driver is disable after sometime

Tags: networking, drivers

I use this driver:

https://github.com/clnhub/rtl8192eu-linux

It works very well but after sometimes, say 2 or 3 weeks, the wifi adapter is not recognized anymore and I need to reinstall the driver again, and then it works well.

What could be the reason ?
Is there anything to do with Ubuntu update ?

**Update:**

```
$ dkms status
bcmwl, 6.30.223.271+bdcom, 5.0.0-29-generic, x86_64: installed
bcmwl, 6.30.223.271+bdcom, 5.0.0-31-generic, x86_64: installed

$ sudo lshw -C network
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection (Lewisville)
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 19
       bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
       logical name: eno1
       version: 04
       serial: 40:2c:f4:ec:79:92
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k firmware=0.13-4 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:27 memory:f7d00000-f7d1ffff memory:f7d39000-f7d39fff ioport:f080(size=32)
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 2
       bus info: usb@1:1.1
       logical name: wlx503eaa3aa20c
       serial: 50:3e:aa:3a:a2:0c
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8192eu ip=192.168.0.105 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn

$ ls -al /usr/src
total 32
drwxr-xr-x  8 root root 4096 Oct 12 14:44 .
drwxr-xr-x 14 root root 4096 Apr 16 21:00 ..
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root 4096 Sep 20 17:06 bcmwl-6.30.223.271+bdcom
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 Jul 25 11:00 libdvd-pkg
drwxr-xr-x 25 root root 4096 Sep 19 20:01 linux-headers-5.0.0-29
drwxr-xr-x  8 root root 4096 Sep 19 20:01 linux-headers-5.0.0-29-generic
drwxr-xr-x 25 root root 4096 Oct  6 12:51 linux-headers-5.0.0-31
drwxr-xr-x  8 root root 4096 Oct  6 12:51 linux-headers-5.0.0-31-generic
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   32 Jul 12 13:51 vboxhost-6.0.10 -> ../share/virtualbox/src/vboxhost

$ ls -al /var/lib/dkms
total 16
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 Sep 20 17:06 .
drwxr-xr-x 75 root root 4096 Sep 20 17:06 ..
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 Oct  6 12:52 bcmwl
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    6 Apr 25  2018 dkms_dbversion
```

Comment: Edit your question and show me `dkms status`. If this command returns nothing, then you need to uninstall the current driver, and reinstall the driver using the dkms instructions in the README.md file.

Comment: @heynnema I updated, it showed the above result, seems like the driver installed properly.

Comment: Edit your question and show me `sudo lshw -C network` and `modinfo rtl8xxxu` and `modinfo 8192eu` and `lsusb`. Your driver isn't showing up in `dkms status`. All I see there is a broadcom driver. Did you blacklist `rtl8xxxu`? Without the new driver, didn't the built-in rtl8xxxu driver find the wireless dongle?

Comment: @heynnema I updated, for 'modinfo 8192eu' , it showed a long information but basically, the "Realtek Wireless Lan Driver" showed up. for 'modinfor rtl8xxxu', the "RTL8XXXu USB mac80211 Wireless LAN Driver" show up. Yes, without new driver, the built-in find the wireless but if I reboot Ubuntu, it could not , and I need to plug out the dongle and plug it in again, that's why I went for this new one.

Comment: You didn't answer/show all of my questions. Did you blacklist rtl8xxxu? `lsusb` would show the device ID for your dongle, and you should be able to `grep` one/more of those values when you `modinfo rtl8xxxu` and `modinfo rtl8192eu`. I don't understand why the 8192eu/rtl8192eu doesn't show up in `dkms status`. Edit your question and show me `ls -al /usr/src` and `ls -al /var/lib/dkms`.

Comment: @heynnema yes , I did blacklist rtl8xxxu. And  `lusbs` showed my dongle, `TP-Link TL-WN821N Version 5 RTL8192EU`. Question is updated.

Comment: And you used `dkms add` and `dkms install` commands to install the new driver?

Comment: @heynnema no, I did not use `dkms add` and `dkms install`, I just clone the source to pc, `make`, `make install`, `modprobe 8192eu`. Seems like I need to do the `dkms`. The Readme actually different with what I had before, that's time no mention about `dkms`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the way your installed the driver, your wifi driver needs to be reinstalled every time the kernel gets updated via Software Updater.

You need to follow the `dkms` install instructions to fix this. See README.md...

## Manual install

Remove available drivers with (skip if sudo lshw -C network and dkms status do not show any wifi drivers):

```
sudo rmmod 8192eu
sudo rmmod rtl8xxxu
sudo dkms remove rtl8192eu/1.0 --all
```

Blacklist default driver (rtl8xxxu on Ubuntu):

```
echo "blacklist rtl8xxxu" >> ./blacklist-rtl8xxxu.conf
sudo mv ./blacklist-rtl8xxxu.conf /etc/modprobe.d/
```

Run add and install commands from driver directory:

```
sudo dkms add .
sudo dkms install rtl8192eu/1.0
```

Load driver (or reboot):

```
sudo modprobe 8192eu
```

Then, `dkms status` should show the rtl8192eu driver as installed.